# Xcode No Devices Registered Error

Tags: xcode, xcode7

[image: There is a Screenshot]

My macbook registered to my apple account which is I'm using on Xcode. Im taking 'no devices registered' warning. How can i fix it ?

Comment: are you trying to launch the project on device? did you add any devices with your apple developer account?

Answer (score 8):

Plug in your own device to your mac, then on Xcode change the simulator to the device you just plugged in, the issue shall be gone.
Change the simulator back to whatever you want if you don't want to work with your own device.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select Organiser from XCode. Now under Devices, select your device. If it is not ready for development then click use for development.
2. If above doesn't solve your problem then from your project settings, set deployment target to one which your app is developed for or lesser.
3. Otherwise there is some issue with certificates and provisioning profiles. Make sure your device's UDID is added in the provisioning profile you are using.

Comment: Thank you but how can i open organizer ? I found under window tab but when i open it there is two more tabs 'Archives' and 'Crashes' and there is nothing about devices. I think I'm opening wrong organizer .

Comment: have u added your developer account ??

Comment: yeah i added my dev account

Comment: have u added your id to your project? if not add your account in prefrence tab in xcode menu

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug even in **Xcode 9 beta**. May be not a bug. When you are trying to get back to a previous version, e.g. the GA version, **you might not see any simulators**.

For me it was caused by updating the iOS develoyment target to version 11. Once I switched back the target to 10.3 the simulator devices reappeared.

Also the beta might have edited the “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION). It is also required to be configured correctly. Back from version 4.0.

Comment: Xcode 9: changed deployment target to 10.3, language version to 3.2 - still didn't work. Sigh...

Comment: I gave up and exited Xcode. When I came back into the project, it magically updated. Hmm... I changed the deployment target and language back, and it was still fine.